# How to install Magento 2.4.4 from archive with sample data?

Tags: magento2.4, setup, zip

i would like to know how to install Magento 2.4.4 starting from the **archive with sample data**.

The archive can be downloaded here: https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#archive-releases

While the docs **should** be here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html

The problem is, that link to the zip install docs redirects to the composer installation docs.

So i'm asking for a step by step guide to install it from the zip. I'm using linux mint 20.3 (ubuntu).

---

Thank you

Comment: Hi aetonsi after the download is complete, just unzip and go inside the unzipped directory and execute the command mentioned  by S.P

Comment: with the procedure by SP, and also following the official guide, i get 404 errors on every static file (js and css). what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working via the following:

- unzip the archive's content in `/var/www/html`
- set file permissions: `sudo su`

  - `chmod 777 . -R ; chown -R :www-data . ; chmod u+x bin/magento`
- edit apache2 config (remove 'indexes' from options, change allowoverride to all): `sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

  ````
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory>```
  ````
- enable apache2 rewrite module: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
- restart apache service: `sudo service apache2 restart`
- run elasticsearch: `elasticsearch-7.17.3/bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid`
- run `bin/magento setup:install` following the official guide https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html#install-magento
- set file permissions again: `sudo chmod 777 . -R`

And it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create virtual host for magento2.4.4. And check your PHP version (must be later php7.4)

**create virtualhost** : https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04/

**Install composer** :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-20-04

**Install elasticsearch**:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-18-04

**Install magento** with composer.

> sudo php bin/magento setup:install
> --base-url="http://www.magento244.com/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="yourdb" --db-user="youruser" --db-password="youarpassword" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin@123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --elasticsearch-host=localhost --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0

**Install Sampledata.**

> sudo php bin/magento sampledata:deploy;

Execute below command and set proper permission.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean;
```

Set permission for your var pub and generated folder.

Comment: hello, i get 404 errors on every static file (css and js), thus the page is completely broken. what can i do?

Comment: your home page load perfect right?

Comment: no, the home page loads broken, with just html content. all the JS and CSS is missing

Comment: check your server settings for

<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

</Directory>

Comment: allowoverride for all

Comment: and restart your server and execute setup:upgrade and static-content command again.

Comment: Ex
<Directory /var/www/html/yourside>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>